# JQuery post method only returning one value

Tags: jquery, post

I'm trying to grab the image property from a data list. But I can only access one value, that is the name in the list via the JQuery post request. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**/api/friends**

```
[
 {
  "name": "Ahmed",
  "image": "http://taylorjonesphoto.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/natural-light-portraits- 
 tacoma-portrait-photographer38-200x300.jpg",
  "score": [
    "5",
    "1",
    "4"
   ]
 },
 {
  "name": "Zara",
  "image": "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e1/04/19/e10419a22a794cd54a8353e299942916.jpg",
  "score": [
   "1",
   "2",
   "3"
  ]
 }
]

module.exports = resultsData;
```

**survey.html**

```
<script>

$.post('api/friends', userData, function(data) {
  console.log(data);
})

</script>
```

All I get is the name. If I try data.image, it returns undefined.

Comment: Are you saying that the POST request returns the array of results you show? (It wouldn't make a lot of sense for a post to do that under normal REST conventions.)

Comment: What is `userData`? Is it used by the server to amend the response? Note that as @DaveNewton says, this should really be a GET request

Comment: I could see this request being a POST, if the user considers this action as a search action, rather than a concrete resource retrieval.  But that discussion is entirely opinionated around the implementation details of REST practices.

Comment: According to W3, the JQuery post method runs a function with additional parameters including "data - contains the resulting data from the request". I would like to display this. But @DaveNewton, you say that is not normal for REST convention?

Comment: @Rory McCrossen: userData is the captured input from an HTML form that I am sending to the server.

Comment: So you’re posting a user creation? What makes you think you’ll get a list of users back?

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I had not added the image to the json response in the express post method. I hadn't posted this file, which contains the api, in the question originally.

So the answer is:

```
res.json({ status: 'Success', name: matchName, image: matchImage });
```

Before it was:

```
res.json({ status: 'Success', name: matchName});
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the array you show in your question.